# How to trigger mouse hover event on anchor tags of drop down list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #0000FF;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ff0000
}
.show {
  display: block;
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button id="myButton" onclick="PrintHello()" class="dropbtn">click</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a class="link" id="Home" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a class="link" id="About1" href="#about">About</a>
    <a class="link" id="Contact" href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to trigger mouse 'hover' event on one of the anchor tag when the drop down menu pop-ups,

I'm using:

```
$("#About1").trigger('hover');
```

It doesn't trigger any event. I have written some event handler for anchor tag for "hover"event. When I use:

```
$("#About1").trigger('mouseover');
```

it calls the event handler but there is no hover effect seen on the web page. I was expecting it to be hovered as same as when you physically hover the mouse on it.
Am I missing something? Is it possible to create such effects by triggering the events? Please do suggest a solution.

Comment: hover is a simplified event for mouseenter and mouseleave.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `hover()` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/789/)

```js
$('button, #myDropdown').hover(function() {
  $('#myDropdown').toggleClass('show');
})
```

Or you can trigger custom event on when you hover (mouseenter) over element [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/790/)

```js
$('#About1').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).trigger('customEvent');
});

$('#About1').on('customEvent', function() {
  alert('Lorem Ipsum');
});
```

Comment: can we automate that mouse hover on anchor tag ?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by `automate`?

Comment: can we trigger mouse hover event on drop down items like Home, About, Contact without physically hovering the mouse on it?

Comment: Just change selector `#About` to `#myDropdown a`

Comment: So you want to trigger `:hover` rules from your css on some other event with js. I don't think that's possible, instead you can put that css rules in one class and `toggleClass` https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/791/ or https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/792/

Answer (score 0):

If you try to change styles only it's better to use selector `:hover` in css.

If you require anything else use hover: `$('selector').hover(functionOnHover,FunctionOnHoverOut);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger mouse hover event on drop down items like for example "About" without physically hovering the mouse on it, you can add

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#About1").trigger('mouseenter');
});`

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xbrewLLz/)